# Is there any way to capture the screen (including the home screen) on iOS9? (private APIs allowed)

Tags: screenshot, ios9, iphone-privateapi

My code, which is using IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface to capture the screen got broken with iOS9.

Do you have a solution which works with iOS9?

Thanks!